# Escaping reserved key words used as variable name in a model

Tags: typescript

I am hoping this isn't a duplicate, been searching around and found nothing, not sure this is even possible or how, if any one can it would be appreciated, definitely reduce a lot of hassle like changing that variable name everywhere and also changing it on every saved data in my database, and there are already over 300 saved data.

My problem is that I'm getting data from the database to my front end with the variable name "new", how can I use it in my Typescript class constructor, or can I? So I'm looking for any form of solution. My backend is done with node.js:

```
product.model.ts
```

```
export class ProductModel {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public title?: string,
        public description?: string,
        public type?: string,
        public data?: string,
        public collections?: any,
        public category?: string,
        public price?: number,
        public sale?: boolean,
        public discount?: number,
        public new?: boolean,
        public quantity?: number,
        public tags?: any,
        public variants?: any,
        public images?: any
    ) {    }
}
```

I have tried using the string form, it didn't work in the constructor.

```
...
public 'new'?: boolean
```

Comment: Not sure how much control of the db you have, but your variabe would be better named `isNew` as it is a boolean.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what I had to do, time is of the essence, thank God I came across a tool called N0SQLBooster for MongoDB it the job for me in the database, that was to easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

`new` is a [reserved keyword](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords) so it is not a [valid variable name](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6).