# Typescript and eslint syntax errors in new code only - ':' expected.ts(1005)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, eslint

I am working in a large react-typescript project and a new and strange problem has started occurring.  I am starting to see supposed syntax errors everywhere, but only in new code that I write.  For example, I am writing a new component:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  new: string;
  old: string;
}

export const ChangeDetail: React.FC<Props> = ({ new, old}: Props) => {
  return null;
}
```

However I am getting the error `':' expected.ts(1005)`:

[image]

As far as I can tell, there is no syntax error here.  In an older component written a few months ago, I have the same exact syntax, but no error:

```
const DateTime: React.FC<Props> = ({
  date,
  timezone = true,
  format
}: Props) => {
  const tz = moment.tz.guess();

  return (
    <Moment
      format={format ?? `MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss ${timezone ? "zz" : ""}`}
      tz={timezone ? tz : undefined}
    >
      {date}
    </Moment>
  );
};
```

I notice that for new code that I'm writing, I am getting very bizzare syntax errors from either typescript or eslint.  Another example:

[image]

Again, as far as I can tell, there is no syntax error here.

I feel like this is an issue with typescript, eslint, or something in my environment.  My package.json lists the following potentially relevant packages:

```
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
```

And in my .eslint.rc:

```js
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 7,
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: "module"
  },
```

When I type `which tsc` or `which typescript`, both are not found (which is fine, as I don't want global installs of typescript conflicting with the local one used in this project).

This has stopped me in my tracks - how might I begin debugging this?  I tried restarting and updating vscode (version 1.62.3), as well as restarting my machine.  What might be going wrong that my linter/compiler is finding syntax errors in new code, where there is none?

Comment: You can't use `new` as a variable name, it's a reserved keyword in the language. That doesn't even work in Javascript much less Typescript.

Comment: Oh god, so dumb.  Its been such a long day / week

Comment: Also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444543/escaping-reserved-key-words-used-as-variable-name-in-a-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` is a reserved keyword in TypeScript, it can't be used as a variable name.

[Reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536#issuecomment-87194347).